# How to make slack app auto pin all new message in a a channel?

Tags: slack

I've been wrestling with trying to get this to work.

I am trying to get slack to set every new message to be pinned to this channel, but cannot figure out if I need to have a timestamp specified and if not, I am not 100% sure how to get this info.

This is through Bolt for Slack apps. Any advice would be ace as this has been giving me a bad brain day haha.

[SS of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJUHH.png)

Comment: Please paste your code into the question instead of an image.

Comment: From the question, the problem is not clear. Can you elaborate the issue ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Slack Auto Pin App](https://slackautopin.rouxtaccess.com/) that does it for you! You just add it to whichever channel and it goes to work.